# FIFA 14 Player Career Mode transfer offers

Tags: fifa-14

So when I have my virtual pro in career mode and I've submitted a transfer request, once I get an offer, can I get a second offer while still considering the first one? or can I only receive one transfer offer at a time? otherwise, what is the point of stalling an offer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can recieve two just dont sign anything and another one will be offered or if you want just turn it down because then the media posts it and clubs go for you